# Define $g(x) = \frac{ f(x)}{f(f(x))}$. Prove or. disprove: If $g$ is unbounded then $\sum 1/f(n)$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f$ be positive non decreasing function s.t. $\lim f(x)$ is $\infty$ as $x$ grows.

Define:

$g(x) = \frac{ f(x)}{f(f(x))}$.

Prove or disprove:

If $g$ is unbounded at $[a, \infty]$ and bounded at $[-\infty, a]$ for every $a>0$ then $\sum 1/f(n)$ diverges.

In my feeling the statement must be true.

My intuition tells me $f(n) = O(n)$ but im not able to prove the statement, so im asking your advice.

How can i continue?

Comment: What's the range and domain of $f$?

Comment: @MathPanda Why does it matter?

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$ for $x\in (0,\infty)$, then $g(x) = 1/x^2$. $g$ is unbounded near $0$ but $\sum 1/f(n)$ converges.

Answer (score 5):

If there  existed  an integer  $\ell$ such that $f(n) >n$ for all $n>\ell$, then monotonicity of $f$ would imply that $f(f(n)) \ge f(n)$ for all $n>\ell$, and this would contradict the hypothesis on $g$.

Thus there must exist $n_k \to \infty$ such that
$f(n_k) \le n_k$, whence
$$\sum_{n=\lfloor n_k/2 \rfloor}^{n_k} \frac1{f(n)} \ge 
\frac{n_k}{2} \cdot \frac1{f(n_k)} \ge 1/2 \,.$$
The tail of a convergent series must tend to $0$, so the series
$\sum_n \frac1{f(n)} $ diverges.